# Probability space in set situation

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let $(A,B,C)$ be a probability space, and consider events $F$, $G$, and $H$ for which $P(F) \gt P(G) \gt P(H) \gt 0$. Events $F$ and $G$ form a partition of $A$, and events $F$ and $ H$ are independent. Can events $G$ and $H$ be disjoint?

Although there is a Hint: Suppose $G$ and $H$ are disjoint, then you will get a contradiction. However, I still have no idea about this, can anyone give me some hint a little more?

Comment: Hint:  The assumptions tell us that $P(F\cap H)=P(F)P(H)$  and $P(G\cap H)=P(G)P(H)$.

Comment: What is the notation "(A,B,C) is a probability space"?

Comment: @coffeemath yes! Let (A,B,C)be a probability space

Comment: You still haven't said what that means... Is A the total space, and one of B,C the function on subsets of A giving their probability? [I asked since I'm not familiar with space defined by a triple...] OR do you just mean A,B,C are events in a probability space? [If the latter there seems no need to do anything with B,C which are not referred to in the rest of the question]

Comment: @coffeemath usually a probability space is defined to be a triple $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega$ is the total space, $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra thereon and $\mathbb{P}$ a probability measure on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$

Comment: @VanillaThunder I thought they were just symbols,i write ABC just because they are convenient

Comment: @coffeemath the questuon does't explain them

Comment: @chargingboy you are perfectly correct, I just used one of the more common symbols, because maybe coffeeboy remembers to have seen something like that. My choice of symbols was no correction to your question. A, B and C have the minor disadvantage that since they are often used to denominate events in a probability space one might (as coffeeboy did) have his expectations towards what A,B,C represent disappointed

Comment: You can use any notations but saying $P(F)$ with $(A,B,C)$ is meaningless. $C(F)$ would be unusual but at least not contradictory.

Comment: What @zoli said. Plus the discourtesy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F$  and $G$ form a partition of $A$ tells us two things, namely

1. $A = F \cup G$, and
2. $F \cap G = \emptyset$

Furthermore, the sample space being $A$ tells us that $H \subseteq (A = F \cup G)$. Clearly, $H \subseteq F$ and/or $H \subseteq G$.

Furthermore, if we consider $P(F) \gt P(G) \gt P(H) \gt 0$, then $H \subset F$ and/or $H \subset G$.

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are disjoint. Then $(H \not\subset G) \rightarrow (H\subset F)$ or in other words, $H \cup F = H$

By the inclusion exclusion principle, $|H \cup F| = |H| = |H| + |F| - |H \cap F| \iff |F| = |H \cap F|$,

which is a contradiction since $P(F) > P(H) \geq P(F \cap H) \iff |F| > |H \cap F|$ .

Comment: Where do you see "the sample space being  $A$" ?

Comment: 'Let $(A,B,C)$ be the probability space'

Comment: Not to be the party pooper, but I feel quite sorry for the OP for accepting this clearly incorrect "answer", which only adds to the OP's existing confusion, instead of helping. First of all, how do you figure that "Clearly, $H\subseteq F$ and/or $H\subseteq G$"??? The fact that $H\subseteq F\cup G$ does **NOT** imply that "$H\subseteq F$ and/or $H\subseteq G$". Here's a counterexample: $F=\{1,2\}$, $G=\{3,4\}$, and $H=\{1,3\}$. Next, using the inclusion/exclusion principle here is unjustified, because we don't know what the probability measure here is, nor do we know that the sets are finite.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $F$ and $G$ form a partition of the space $A$ means that $F\cup G=A$ and $F\cap G=\varnothing$. If we suppose that $G$ and $H$ are disjoint, then necessarily $H\subseteq F$. In fact, $H\subsetneq F$ — they can't be equal because $P(F)>P(H)$. Now state the definition of independence of two events, and see that this equation (that defines independence) cannot hold true — that will be the desired contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand this relation:If we suppose that $G$ and $H$ are disjoint, then necessarily $ H \subseteq F$.Why?And the question said that $F$ and $H$ are independent,if $ H \subseteq F$ or $ H \subset F$ ,$H$ and $F$ should be dependent

Comment: concerning $H\subset F$ : because $F$ and $G$ are a partition of the total space

Comment: @chargingboy: This may be an overkill, but here's one way to show that. Note that $H=H\cap A=H\cap(F\cup G)=(H\cap F)\cup(H\cap G)=(H\cap F)\cup\varnothing=H\cap F$, and $H=H\cap F$ implies $H\subseteq F$. Or simply draw a picture.

Comment: @VanillaThunder,i am not understand your explanation,you said $F$ and $G$ are a partition of the total space,but the question just said that $F$ and $G$ form a partition of $A$.The total space should be $A,B,C$ right?

Comment: @chargingboy: No, not right. I'm afraid the real problem here is that you don't even know what you're talking about, as evidenced by your comment above about writing $A$, $B$, $C$ as "just symbols". They are not just symbols -- each one of them represents something and means something. Before even attempting to solve any exercises on a topic, you should make an effort and find out what the topic is about. So please read and study and think about the definition of a probability space. You're welcome to ask questions here on Math.SE if you need help understanding it. Then move on to exercises.